# 2 Main problems with my Code

Tags: c

This is what my yes() code looks like. Im trying to make it so that if the user enters anything other than 'y' 'Y' 'n' 'N' . I solved the problem for entering anything other than those letters but if i were to type Yes or No it only takes the first char which makes the function think its one of those letters.
I dont know how to fix that.

```
        int yes(void) {
        char singleLetter = ' ';  
        int finalValue = -1; 
        int theResult = 0; 

        scanf(" %c", &singleLetter);
        clearKeyboard();

        do
        {
            switch (singleLetter)
            {

            case 'Y':
            case 'y':
                finalValue = 1;
                theResult = 1;
                break;

            case 'N':
            case 'n':
                finalValue = 0;
                theResult = 1;
                break;
            default:
                theResult = 0;
                printf("Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable: ");
                scanf("%c", &singleLetter);
                clearKeyboard();
            }
        } while (!theResult);

        return finalValue;

    }
```

The second problem i have is that I was given this statement:

> The purpose of this function is to set the values for a Contact using
>   the pointer parameter variable (set the Contact it points to).
>
> Use the pointer parameter received to this function to supply the
>   appropriate Contact member to the “get” functions (getName,
>   getAddress, and getNumbers) to set the values for the Contact.

This is currently whats on the "get" section:

```
void getName(struct Name *contactName) {

            printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
            scanf("%s", (*contactName).firstName);
            printf("Do you want to enter a middle intial(s)? (y or n): ");

            if (yes() == 1) {
                printf("Please enter the contact's middle intial(s): ");
                scanf("%s", (*contactName).middleInitial);

            }

            printf("Please enter the contact's last name: ");
            scanf("%s", (*contactName).lastName);
        }

        // getAddress:
        void getAddress(struct Address *

contactAddress) {


        printf("Please enter the contact's street number: ");

        (*contactAddress).streetNumber == getInt();

        printf("Please enter the contact's street name: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", (*contactAddress).street);

        printf("Do you want to enter an apartment number? (y or n): ");

        if (yes() == 1) {
            printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
            scanf("%d", (*contactAddress).apartmentNumber);
        }

        printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", (*contactAddress).postalCode);
        printf("Please enter the contact's city: ");
        scanf("%s", (*contactAddress).city);
    }

    // getNumbers:


    // getNumbers:
    // NOTE:  Also modify this function so the cell number is
    //        mandatory (don't ask to enter the cell number)
    void getNumbers(struct Numbers *contactNumber) {

        printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
        scanf(" %s", (*contactNumber).cell);
        printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n) ");

        if (yes() == 1) {
            printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
            scanf("%s", (*contactNumber).home);
        }

        printf("Do you want to enter a business number? (y or n) ");

        if (yes() == 1) {
            printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
            scanf("%s", (*contactNumber).business);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Then i have this below it. And im not sure what to program for this part. I tried putting what Is right (but obviously its wrong)

```
   void getContact(struct Contact *contact) {
        getName(contact);
        getAddress(contact);
        getNumbers(contact);
    }
```

These are what my professor declared (so i cant change this part):

```
getContact(&contact);
    printf("\nValues Entered:\n");
    printf("Name: %s %s %s\n", contact.name.firstName, contact.name.middleInitial, contact.name.lastName);
    printf("Address: %d|%s|%d|%s|%s\n", contact.address.streetNumber, contact.address.street, 
        contact.address.apartmentNumber, contact.address.postalCode, contact.address.city);
    printf("Numbers: %s|%s|%s\n", contact.numbers.cell, contact.numbers.home, contact.numbers.business);
```

This is whats in my header file:

```
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};

// Structure type Address declaration
// Place your code here...
struct Address {
    char street[41];
    int streetNumber[1];
    int apartmentNumber[1];
    char postalCode[8];
    char city[41];
};


// Structure type Numbers declaration
// Place your code here...
struct Numbers {
    char cell[21];
    char home[21];
    char business[21];
};


// Structure type Contact declaration
// Place your code here...
struct Contact {
    struct Name name;
    struct Address address;
    struct Numbers numbers;
};



//------------------------------------------------------
// Function Prototypes
//------------------------------------------------------

// +-------------------------------------------------+
// | NOTE:  Copy/Paste your Assignment-2 Milestone-1 |
// |        function prototypes here...              |
// +-------------------------------------------------+


// Get and store from standard input the values for Name
// Place your code here...
void getName(struct Name *);

// Get and store from standard input the values for Address
// Place your code here...
void getAddress(struct Address *);

// Get and store from standard input the values for Numbers
// Place your code here...
void getNumbers(struct Numbers *);

// Get and store from standard input the values for a Contact
// Place your code here...
void getContact(struct Contact *);
```

The results when i run the program with the follow instructions

```
------------------------------------------
Testing: getContact(struct Contact *)
------------------------------------------
Please enter the contact's first name: Andrew
Do you want to enter a middle intial(s)? (y or n): n
Please enter the contact's last name: Random
Please enter the contact's street number: 100
Please enter the contact's street name: Rain
Do you want to enter an apartment number? (y or n): y
Please enter the contact's apartment number: 14
Please enter the contact's postal code: Z8Z 7Q7
Please enter the contact's city: Toronto
Please enter the contact's cell phone number: 647-999-9999
Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n) n
Do you want to enter a business number? (y or n) n


Values Entered:
Name: 647-999-9999  Random
Address: 13630948||13630952||
Numbers: ||
```

As you can see, my name is my cell number, the last name works, the address does not work at all, and the numbers are not there.

Comment: I only read the first paragraph, but if you want to handle input as "Yes" or "No", a char is not the correct datatype. You need a string.

Comment: Is this C or C++ or Objective-c? Please pick one

Comment: Recommend removing most of those language tags. Looks more like C than C++ or objective-C, so you're likely to have less re-writing if you go with C.

Comment: @DeiDei i have changed it to

 char singleLetter[100];  
 int finalValue = -1; 
 int theResult = 0; 

 scanf(" %s", &singleLetter[0]);
 clearKeyboard();

 do
 {
  switch (singleLetter[0])

but its the same results

Comment: `switch (singleLetter[0])` still only checks for the first character. A `switch` is not the tool for the job.

Comment: @DeiDei then what should i be using

Comment: @Ham You only want to accept 'y', 'Y', 'n' and 'N', right? Check if the length of the string is 1, if so, do the switch, otherwise it's wrong input.

Comment: @DeiDei I have fixed the Yes and No problem with fgets. Do u know what the other problem im having means?

Comment: can you also post the function which calls ```getContact()```

Answer (score 0):

I believe major problem is, that in getContact() function you pass pointer to Contact structure while functions getName() etc. require pointers to inside structures (e.g. Name). Change it to:

```
void getContact(struct Contact *contact) {
        getName(&contact->name);
        getAddress(&contact->address);
        getNumbers(&contact->numbers);
    }
```

Please start reading warning messages!

Comment: I've done that. But i end up getting the error undefined reference to `getContact' in my main which has 

struct Contact contact = { { {0} } };
getContact(&contact);
    printf("\nValues Entered:\n");
    printf("Name: %s %s %s\n", contact.name.firstName, contact.name.middleInitial, contact.name.lastName);
    printf("Address: %d|%s|%d|%s|%s\n", contact.address.streetNumber, contact.address.street, 
contact.address.apartmentNumber, contact.address.postalCode, 
contact.address.city);
printf("Numbers: %s|%s|%s\n", contact.numbers.cell, contact.numbers.home, contact.numbers.business);